# Why is @BeforeClass not firing?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, testng-dataprovider

This is one Cucumber Scenario Outline taken from an existing code base, but I've been asked to try it with TestNG. Some of the stuff (scenario(), scenarios(), TestNGCucumberRunner, DataProvider) has been taken from another post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701094/how-to-implement-and-run-cucumber-test-files-using-testng), as I couldn't figure out how to make a Scenario Outline play nice with TestNG.

```java
public class StepsSettings {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private SettingsPage settingsPage;
    private SearchBlock searchBlock;
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @Test
    @Given("maximum results per page is set to {int}")
    public void maximumResultsPerPageIsSetTo(int results) {
        settingsPage = new SettingsPage(driver);
        searchBlock = new SearchBlock(driver);
        settingsPage.navigateTo();
        settingsPage.setNumberOfResults(results);
    }

    @Test
    @When("the user searches for {string} in collection {string}")
    public void theUserSearchesForInCollection(String key, String collection) {
        searchBlock.performSearch(key, collection);
    }

    @Test
    @Then("the number of publications displayed is no more than {int}")
    public theNumberOfPublicationsDisplayedIsNoMoreThan(int count) {
        By articlesBy = By.cssSelector("article");

        Assert.assertTrue(settingsPage.getObjects(articlesBy).size() <= count);
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber scenarios", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickleEvent, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty(
            "webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
        );
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

On execution, the only error is a NullPointerException, due to @BeforeClass not firing where *WebDriver driver* gets its value.

The part dealing with Scenario Outlines I don't fully understand, but at least I'm not getting the *cannot inject @test annotated method with* error anymore.

Comment: looks need to use before/afterclass in test class instead of steps class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325450/how-to-execute-cucumber-step-defination-with-testng-annotation

Answer (score 0):

Methods annotated with Before/AfterClass HAVE to be static.

Comment: Are you very sure about this? I have seen multiple examples on the web and I've tested it in its simplest form, and the methods do not need to be static. I know that with Junit they have to be, but my question is specifically about TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

Please use @BeforeTest instead of @BeforeClass. If the problem is solved, try to understand the flow of test annotation here. Or comment here for further help.

Comment: \@BeforeTest gives me the same result. Also, I would like to use \@BeforeClass since I want it to fire once only, before the first method of the class, not before each method.